# Deleting values on Hana Table based on a field value

Tags: sql, database, procedure, hana

I am working on a hana table and i am trying to delete a table if it contains value from a list.

```
A  B   
22 01 
22 01
22 02
22 06
23 01
23 01
23 06
```

I will like to drop some values from this table and have this.

```
A  B   
22 01 
22 01
22 06
23 01
23 01
23 06
```

Basically i will like to most likely do a count and check if column B consists of 01 AND 02, if it does drop 02 and if it consists of only 01 leave as it is.

This seems virtually impossible with almost every sql script i have tried

```
SELECT BP, COUNT(*) AS SO FROM "EH"."BP_CUST" GROUP BY BP;
```

This scripts gets the count of each row and put it in SO column.

after that maybe do an if statement on the SO column and delete if the B field contains 01 and 02?

I tried doing and IF statement then select and i could not get it to work either.

```
A  B
22 01 
22 01 
22 02 
22 06 
23 01 
23 01 
23 06 
24 02

Becomes 

A  B
22 01 
22 01 
22 06 
23 01 
23 01 
23 06 
24 02
```

Comment: What if your data is like this:

22 01 
22 01
22 02
22 06
23 01
23 01
23 06
24 02

What is your desired output?

Comment: @LonelyPlaneteer i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
select c.*
from "EH"."BP_CUST" c
where c.b <> '02' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from "EH"."BP_CUST" c2 
                  where c2.a = c.a and c2.b = '01'
                 );
```

Your question says "delete".  But I think the intention is to select "02" rows only when there is no "01" row for the same `a` (and all other rows).

Comment: yes i want to select 02 rows when is no 01, and select 01 rows if there is 01 and 02 but this select both 01 and 02 regardless.

Thanks for the help though

Comment: This should not be selecting `'02'` rows when there are `'01'` rows (neither condition is met).

Comment: so if there is 22 01 
22 01 
22 02 
22 06
23 02
23 06

how do i select 
22 01 
22 01 
22 06
23 02
23 06
keep in mind that i want to leave 23 02 and 23 06

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this might be the solution:

```sql
DELETE BP_CUST 
    WHERE A IN 
    (
        SELECT
            BP_CUST.A
        FROM
        (   
            SELECT
                A
                , COUNT(CASE WHEN B != '02' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NOT_02 
                , COUNT(CASE WHEN B = '02' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS IS_02
            FROM BP_CUST
            GROUP BY A
        ) AS t_delete
        JOIN BP_CUST ON BP_CUST.A = t_delete.A
        WHERE B = '02' AND NOT_02 > 0 AND IS_02 > 0
    )
    AND B = '02'
```

Comment: i tried using this code and it wasnt working. i dont think i can do  something like BP_CUST.A in hana. 

Thank you tho